# What is the difference between $Q=\Delta U+W$ and $\Delta U=Q+W$?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, conventions

Is $Q=\Delta U+W$ for when the the work is done from the system while $\Delta U=Q+W$ is for when the work is done by the system?  Will anybody explain this to me, please?

When do we use $Q=\Delta U+W$ and when do we use $\Delta U=Q+W$?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66972/.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37904/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a matter of convention. The [sign convention of Clausius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_law_of_thermodynamics#Description) and the sign convention of IUPAC are the two prevailing sign conventions. Both of these assign a sign to the work done differently. The former, used primarily in physics assign a positive sign to the work done by the system while the latter assigns positive sign to the work done on the system. Hence, according to the convention youe are following, the form of the First law of thermodynamics will change:-
$$Q=\Delta U+W \quad \text{(Clausius convention)}$$
$$\Delta U=Q+W \quad \text{(IUPAC convention)}$$

Comment: And you agree with your colleagues which one you will use and *stick to it*. Anyone who differs must be fed to the wolves. Or something.

Comment: @dmckee I believe that they are fed to Cthluthu

Comment: Best answer ever found