# A contradiction to the first law of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, work, conventions

When a block slips on a rough surface, the work done by the surface on block is negative, while the work done by block on surface is zero. While writing the first law of thermodynamics, I have considered the block as my system and surface as the surroundings.

Now here's the poblem: by the first law if thermodynamics, we have:

$$\Delta U=Q+W$$

The equation works for the block as a system ($Q=0$ and its energy goes down by $-W$), but does not seem to work-out for the table because positive work was done on it.

Comment: There is no convention, the work on a system has its own sign. The fact that sometimes the work on the system and the one on the external system are equal up to the sign is not matter of convention, when it is true. Here it is false. The correct equation is the second one, but the LHS should also include the kinetic energy of the block.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/664079/2451

Comment: Hi Anonymous. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: You asked two questions actually. The sign convention took most of the space and was repeat. I answered both though so youre good

Comment: In this version you accidentally had one if them say delta Un= Q, without a W. Thats why originally had thst in my answer

Comment: @Qmechanic This question used to ask two questions: 1. about two forms of the first law that used different sign conventions. For that aspect, it was flagged as a duplicate, as the linked question shows. 2. Where the friction energy goes and how the first law (in any form and regardless of sign convention) appears to be broken when seen from the table’s viewpoint. | It was then edited and no longer asks what the linked question asks. So is that just a community mod failure and let it go? Or is there a question that it *is* still a duplicate of even now. If so what question?

Comment: Or I could call it a failure by me to make it immediately clear how it was now different

Comment: Kinetic friction with a discontinuity in velocity at the interface between the block and table is just an idealization (model).  Another model, which may satisfy you a little better is to envision a very thin intermediate layer sandwiched between the block and table, like a viscous fluid.  The layer is experiencing a shearing deformation, so the top of the layer is moving with the velocity of the block, and the bottom at the table is stationary.  So at the top, the work done by the block on the layer is minus the work done by the layer on the block.

Comment: But at the bottom, neither the layer of the table is doing work.  If you apply the first law of thermodynamics to the layer, the work being done at the top of the layer by the block is equal to the heat flowing out of the layer to both the block and table (assuming that the layer is very thin and has negligible internal energy change).

Answer (score 2):

Good question.

The first law with those terms is just a subset (special case) of the law of conservation of energy (which technically is a special case of the law of conservation of energy-matter). If we assume matter is not being converted to or from energy, then energy is conserved, and matter is conserved.

Some laws can be broken by introducing things that aren’t included (things assumed during the law’s statement to be held constant, or even stuff that hadn’t been discovered when the law was first formulated). Also, the sign for work is sometimes a convention. Usually we have to just work-out which way the energy flows.

In the case of the block, it is losing kinetic energy and it is breaking bonds in the matter comprising the surface, bonds that hold negative energy, and also heating-up both block and surface. Like bending a bar takes work, and so it puts energy into the bar; the bar has more bond energy (sometimes called cold working) than before it was bent.

We tend to think of friction energy as just disappearing, but it does go somewhere, usually in bending or breaking and/or generating heat.

Same logic applies to conservation of momentum. The block loses momentum and it may seem like it disappeared, but the earth/table/block system still has the same total momentum. The earth (excluding the block) now has a drop more rotation and/or translation after stopping the block.