# Sign of work in adiabatic expansion

Tags: thermodynamics, work, conventions

I know that in an adiabatic expansion, $W = -U.$ My question is, is the work positive or negative? I'm confused on the difference between work done "by" the system and work done "on" the system.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37904/2451 and links therein.

Comment: You can use both convention. But you have to use 2 versions of the first law for 2 conventions. Then you can deduce whether work done on / by is positive from the fact whether the volume is increased or decreased.

Answer (score 3):

The most common expression for the first law is

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$ where

$W$ is positive if work is done ***by the system*** (work out, energy out) and negative if done **on the system** (work in, energy in). An expansion is considered work done by the system.

But sometimes in chemical thermodynamics it is expressed as

$$\Delta U=Q+W$$ where

$W$ is negative if work is done ***by the system*** (work out, energy out) and positive  if done **on the system** (work in, energy in).

It doesn't matter as long as you are consistent. Think of like this. If energy is going out of the system, there will be a reduction (negative change) in internal energy, and vice versa. Both versions are consistent with this. And of course, $Q=0$ in both cases for an adiabatic process.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Work done $by$ the system is positive. This is just a convention and interestingly the opposite convention about the sign of work is taken in chemistry.

Answer (score 0):

Work is equal to the product of force and displacement.  So if the force that A exerts on B is in the same direction as the displacement of B, the work that A does on B is positive.  If the force that A exerts on B is opposite to the direction of B's displacement, then the work that A does on B is negative.

In the equation that you have written, W is the work that the system does on its surroundings.  It can be either positive or negative in sign, depending on whether the gas expands or is compressed, respectively.